# Is org.apache.naming.resources package have been removed in tomcat 8.0.20?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm working on migrating embedded tomcat 7 project to latest release of **tomcat 8.0.20**
When compiling the project, I'm getting compilation errors saying that `org.apache.naming.resources` package can't be found. I've checked the Tomcat API doc too. It seems that the package doesn't exists there.

Is that package removed from tomcat 8? 
If so what is/are the alternative(s) ?

I couldn't found any source saying that it is been removed or deprecated.

P.S
I'm using `DirContextURLStreamHandler` which was resided in above package in tomcat 7

Comment: You probably don't use all the classes in this package. Which classes specifically are you missing?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I want to use DirContextURLStreamHandler class. I've updated the question as well.

Comment: I got the some problem now with another class of this lib (ProxyDirContext). Did you find out what was the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I didnt find any official detailed documents about this yet but i think it is replaced by the apache tomcat-catalina library.
In my pom.xml i replaced the naming lib

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>naming-resources</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.23</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In my case i needed to replace the ProxyDirContext class with the StandardRoot class from this new lib.
From what i ve seen so far for Tomcat 8 they use a new implementation.
See also https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Internal_APIs

> A new Resources implementation that merges Aliases, VirtualLoader,
>   VirtualDirContext, JAR resources and external repositories into a
>   single framework rather than a separate one for each feature.