# Tomcat upgrade: How to find information on classes that are no longer available

Tags: tomcat, upgrade

I am upgrading our app from tomcat 5 to a newer version. At first I tried to upgrade to 10.x but that was soon abandoned as many of the third party classes that it uses do not support jakarta.servlet which replaced javax.servlet. Trying to upgrade to tomcat 9.x, I am finding several classes that are no longer available, for example, org.apache.naming.JndiPermission (in 8 but not 9), org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLStreamHandler (in 7 but not 8), ... These classes were not marked as deprecated, so it is puzzling why they would disappear.

The official upgrade guides for each version has been reviewed and does not mention any of those classes. A general google search has not returned any information either.

Is there any suggestion on how to find information about those classes and their replacements?

Comment: This post was quite a bit of help in addressing several of those issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895226/is-org-apache-naming-resources-package-have-been-removed-in-tomcat-8-0-20

Comment: Just `org.apache.naming` no longer being available doesn't mean anything, and it wouldn't need to be deprecated: This is a non-tomcat library that is (well, apparently _was_) bundled with Tomcat and it looks like it no longer is bundled or visible to web applications by default. You _might_ simply need to bring your own dependencies rather than relying on them being available from the platform you use. (provided as comment, because it rather talks about the problem with the expectation rather than providing a solution)

Comment: Most classes, except those documented, are internal to Tomcat and can disappear without any notice. What did you use the `DirContextURLStreamHandler` for?

Comment: The code, which was developed by a different organization and now we own it, has:         "URLStreamHandlerFactory streamHandlerFactory =
            new DirContextURLStreamHandlerFactory(); URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(streamHandlerFactory);" There are no other references to that object/class anywhere else in the code. What should it be replaced with?